# Can i use Power BI Embedded with my own user authentication database

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I developed my own user database that I integrated with my Customer-Facing Web Portal. Each customer has a login/password that is stored in my own user db.

I Would like to know if can i use the Power BI embedded to embed a dashboard in my Web Portal and use Row Level Security to restrict access to some data based on User or another attribute (like "COMPANYNAME")?

Thanks!

Comment: For sure you can, in many different ways. Can you share the approaches / docs / tutorials you've tried so far? As it stands, your question is kindof a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42455799/419956) that was closed by others as being "too broad".